# get active directory user name with PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, wamp

I am using WAMP 3.1 with php 5.6 on Windows machine.
Could you please help me with some good guide how can I get Active Directory user name of user on my index.php page? For example:

```
Hello "USER1" from "MYDOMAIN"
```

This is what i tried so far but no success:

```
print $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
print $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
print $_SERVER['LOGON_USER'];
print $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
print $_SERVER['REDIRECT_LOGON_USER'];
print $_SERVER['REDIRECT_AUTH_USER'];
```

Only think that works is get users domain with:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to exec an external command.  IIRC All of the php ownership functions like `fileowner()` only work on posix.

Comment: i have tried also these two modules:
`LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so`
`LoadModule auth_ntlm_module modules/mod_authn_ntlm.so` but still no success

Comment: oh you want to login using active directory on your homepage?  If that is the case, use the ldap extension to php.  You will want to bind to your `OU` as the authenticating user.  Check for LDAP injection!

Comment: By 'user1' from 'MYDOMAIN', do you mean the referer domain?